# I am getting an error invalid operands of types const char [42] and double to binary 'operator+'

Tags: c++

I am getting an error

> invalid operands of types const char [42] and double to binary
>   'operator+'

```
QSqlQuery update_values;
update_values.prepare("UPDATE cropdatabase1 SET CropLatitude = '"+latitude+"', CropLongitude = '"+longitude+"', SownDate = '"+SownDate+"', Status = '1',Where UNC = '"+unc+"'" );
update_values.exec();
```

Comment: Please format your code properly using the provided button.

Comment: Use prepared statements and bind values like the doc says, will make most of the pain and security bugs go away.

Comment: I see another issue: There is a extra comma `,` before the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: What are types of the variables: `latitude`, `longitude`, `SownDate` and `unc`?

Comment: One of the variables you're trying to concatenate isn't a string, but even if it was that's not the right way to do it. Can't tell you which one because you haven't included enough code.

Comment: So one or more of your variables are of type `double`. You cannot add a `double` to a string. You might be able to use `std::to_string(x)` to get a conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in C++ you can't concatenante strings with other types like it would be done in Javascript. 
You need to tranform you variables in strings and then concatenate all of theses.

My solution uses stringstreams, wich have the operators defined to push various native types into the stream. Then you can just get the final string from the stream.

```
std::ostringstream update_cmd;

update_cmd << "UPDATE cropdatabase1 SET CropLatitude = '";
update_cmd << latitude;
update_cmd << "', CropLongitude = '";
update_cmd << longitude;
update_cmd << "', SownDate = '";
update_cmd << SownDate;
update_cmd << "', Status = '1',Where UNC = '";
update_cmd << unc;

QSqlQuery update_values;
update_values.prepare(update_cmd.str());
update_values.exec();
```